# How can I decrease the price using the same number used to increase?

Tags: javascript, react-native, vue-native

I'm trying to decrease the price when the user presses the minus icon using the initial price, but then the new price after increasing is the initial price

```
quantityHandler: function (action, product) {
      // Increase or decrease quantity of product
      try {
        const newItems = [...this.products]; // clone the array
        let idx = newItems.indexOf(product);
        let currentQty = newItems[idx].productQuantity;
        let price = newItems[idx].unitPrice;

        if (action == "more") {
          newItems[idx].productQuantity = currentQty + 1;
          newItems[idx].unitPrice = price + price;
        } else if (action == "less") {
          newItems[idx].productQuantity = currentQty > 1 ? currentQty - 1 : 1;
          // Decrease current price using the initial price
        }

        this.products = newItems; // set new state
        console.log(this.products);
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    },
```

Comment: Then you'll have to keep track of the unaltered products array in your state, and use another property for the *altered* prices, not the same.

Comment: It seems odd that you are editing the `unitPrice`. Unit price should be the price for one unit of the product, which is what you could use to perform your calculation. You are treating the unitPrice property as gross price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
quantityHandler: function (action, product) {
      // Increase or decrease quantity of product
      try {
        const newItems = [...this.products]; // clone the array
        let idx = newItems.findIndex((item) => { //compare with some unique identifier
         return item.id === product.id
        })
        let currentQty = newItems[idx].productQuantity;
        let price = newItems[idx].unitPrice;
        let perQtyPrice = price / currentQty  //per unit price
        if (action == "more") {
          newItems[idx].unitPrice += perQtyPrice;
          newItems[idx].productQuantity = currentQty + 1;
        } else if (action == "less") {
          if(currentQty > 1) {
           newItems[idx].unitPrice -= perQtyPrice;
           newItems[idx].productQuantity = currentQty > 1 ? currentQty - 1 : 1;
          }
        }

        this.products = newItems; // set new state
        console.log(this.products);
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    },
```

You need to find the per item price then use that to subtract or add to the price

Comment: My initial line `let idx = this.products.indexOf(product);` actually gets the right quantity being modified. I tired the your code `let idx = newItems.findIndex((item) => {return item.id === product.id})`, and modifying the quantity of another item on the list modified the first item's quantity instead. Thanks for the `perQtyPrice`, it gets the desired output.

Answer (score -1):

You can use negative numbers. Something like:

```
newPrice = currentQty * price
newPactionrice = 'less'? newPrice = newPrice * -1
// then add that price... + a negative number will decrease the total
```

Comment: I don't think you read the question very well. The OP is already subtracting successfully. Their question is a different one.